# Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_lN2796".tex

Tags: errors

If I try to build a new file on Tex Studio I get the following error message

"Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_lN2796".tex"

and nothing basically moves.

Has it ever happened to anybody?

Thanks
Manuel

Comment: have you installed tex? the usual reason for that error is installing an editor such as tex studio with no tex system.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Could%20not%20start%20the%20command%3a%20pdflatex.exe%20-synctex%3d1%20

Comment: Thank you very much! I now downloaded MikTex and it started to work.